# Create mongoose connection behind the university proxy?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, proxy

I am building A MERN stack app on linux. The internet only work when we use proxy server of college. I am using   **mongoose** for creating connection with MongoDB Atlas. The issue is that **mongoose** is unable to connect to MongoDB although i already set the proxy. How can I create connection in **mongoose** through **university proxy server** with MongoDB Atlas.

Currently mongoose connection is setup like this:

```
const CONNECTION_URL =process.env.CLUSTER_URL;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`server running at PORT ${PORT}`);
    }),
  )
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Currently university is using HTTP_PROXY=http://172.16.100.7:3022.

Comment: Since when use mongodb a HTTP_PROXY? Why not install mongodb localy when developing? I dont see a benfit from using Atlas here, especially when you have to use a proxied connection. The proxy musst support that, if thats not given & the firewall blocks everything else you have no chance to use mongodb atlas. Are you able to SSH into a server on the internet? Then you can build a reverse tunnel. (If  you use a linux/unix based OS); Perhaps if your proxy supports SOCKS. Perhaps.

Comment: I am just starting out with mongoose-db. Atlas provide quite intuitive way to see the data. I face this issue various time, where corporate proxy is necessary to  interact with Firebase  or MongoDB.

Comment: Is it possible tunnel whole traffic of project through corporate proxy? I tried but did not find any good solution.

Comment: Checkout a custom agent, that implements the socks protocl. https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-socks-proxy-agent This works only if your campus proxy allow/supports socks connections.